# Ignore UnsignedProperties

Tags: xades4j

On verifying a signature containing `UnsignedProperties`, I got he following exception:

```
Caused by: xades4j.xml.unmarshalling.PropertyUnmarshalException: Unsupported properties were found
    at xades4j.xml.unmarshalling.FromXmlUnsupportedUSPLimiter.convertFromObjectTree(FromXmlUnsupportedUSPLimiter.java:44)
    at xades4j.xml.unmarshalling.FromXmlUnsupportedUSPLimiter.convertFromObjectTree(FromXmlUnsupportedUSPLimiter.java:26)
    at xades4j.xml.unmarshalling.UnmarshallerModule.convertProperties(UnmarshallerModule.java:64)
    at xades4j.xml.unmarshalling.DefaultQualifyingPropertiesUnmarshaller.unmarshalProperties(DefaultQualifyingPropertiesUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at xades4j.verification.XadesVerifierImpl.verify(XadesVerifierImpl.java:168)
```

Is there an option to just ignore those on verification, instead of throwing the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is thrown because *some* of the unsigned properties in your signature are not supported. Currently there's no option to turn that check off, because the signature verification would be incomplete...

Comment: If I wanted to add an implementation for those properties, is there a provider I could implement, or would I need to alter the source-code of _xades4j_?

Comment: You'd need to replace the whole unmarshaller, or change the existing source code to remove the check that is causing the exception.